# get contacts distributiongroups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, contacts

I'm creating a script to manage contacts and users on `Exchange 2010` via `Powershell`. Especially we try to get all distributiongroups of a contact/user.

Is there a way to get the distribution groups of a contact/user? Perhabs without searching in all distributiongroups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using Get-ADObject using the contact's guid:

```
$contact = Get-MailContact domainname\contactname
(Get-ADObject -Identity $contact.Guid -Properties 'MemberOf').MemberOf
```

Comment: How do I do this with Office365 online?  I can't use get-adoObject

Answer (score 1):

I had errors following the command above, the following tweek worked for me.

> (Get-ADObject -Identity $contact.Guid -Properties 'MemberOf' |
>   Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf